# Converting array into object and call a function on it

Tags: php, typecast-operator

I have an array returned by a query. I want the array to be an object, so I write:

```
$object = (object)($array);
```

I want to call a method on $object, but when I launch:

```
$object->getUsername();
```

I got this error:

```
Attempted to call method "getName" on class "stdClass".
```

How to access the data of the object?

This is part of my class:

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserLicense", mappedBy="user_id")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Currency", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_currency", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $currency;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;
```

This is the query I'm using via Doctrine:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $currency = $em->getRepository('UserBundle\Entity\User')->findBy(array('email' => $userMail));
```

Comment: @RyanVincent Edited!

Comment: @RyanVincent yes, via Doctrine. Added

Comment: `Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given`

Answer (score 1):

When you're casting array to object, it created `stdClass` instance.

It's a simple object with all public properties.

So simply access them like this:

```
$object->name;
```

Here's a working example: https://3v4l.org/Ui9uY

Comment: I got this: `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name`

Comment: Did the array have `name` index?

Comment: Maybe can you do a var_dump() on your array so we can see what's inside ?

Comment: Yes, there was a `name` index

Comment: Show an example of the array you are converting

Comment: This is part of it: `array(1) { [0]=> object(UserBundle\Entity\User)#615 (32) { ["id":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> int(65) ["currency":protected]=> object(Proxies\__CG__\UserBundle\Entity\Currency)#587 (7) { ["__initializer__"]=> object(Closure)#618 (3) { ["static"]=> array(2) { ["entityPersister"]=> object(Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister)#616 (14) { ["class":protected]=> object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)#579 (37) { ["name"]=> string(32) `

Comment: If you could add the entire array to the answer, that would be grate...

Comment: Thanks, I finally solved calling the right Doctrine query. Instead of using the `findBy` I called `findOneBy` method and I got directly an object.

Answer (score 0):

In order this to work you must transform that array into an object that has that methods that you need.

When you use `(object) $array` it will assign the class `stdClass` which is a generic class in php that has no methods. So you won't have your required methods in there.

You should create a class with a desired signature and when you instantiate the object pass the array in the constructor and save it as a property or each pair `key=>value` to be a property with the coresponding value.

For example:

```
$userData = ['name' => 'John', 'email' => 'test@example.com'];

class User
{
    property $name;
    property $email;

    public function __construct(array $userData)
    {
        // here you'll need some data validation but is not case for this example
        $this->name = $userData['name'];
        $this->email = $userData['email'];
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}

$user = new User($userData);

echo $user->getName();
```

This way every object in the application will have a specific type and it will help you in time. Also, you can use an interface for the object.